# role matrix case status

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using select box for send data. Sentence part only admin and manager can send data. Example, only admin and manager can select one and two. Normal user can't select it. Just for [reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-gbnnm8).

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="gender">
   <option value="A">All</option><br>
      <option *ngFor="let option of selectOptions" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </option>
</select>
<p>
{{ "selectedOption: " + selectedOption }}
</p>
```

**Component**

```
 this.userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
 public selectOptions = [
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three"
  ];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look it out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-65hm48), may this helps you !

class file

```
   userRole: string = 'manager'; // localStorage.getItem('role');
```

Template file

You can `disabled` `attribute` in `option`, when user is not admin or manager and option value is one or two disabled the option

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="gender">
       <option value="A">All</option><br>
          <option *ngFor="let option of selectOptions"
            [value]="option" 
            [disabled]="!(userRole == 'admin' || userRole == 'manager') && (option === 'One' || option === 'Two')"
          >{{option}}
          </option>
    </select>
    <p>
    {{ "selectedOption: " + selectedOption }}
    </p>
```